# Use JQuery to get values of a list that's not defined using HTML

Tags: jquery

I define my list like this (it's getting the response from a preceding function):

```
var people = response.list;
```

What I'm trying to do is find a way to get a console message to display the elements of the list.  The list's length is 3 so it isn't long at all.

All of the examples I found are built off using the actual tags in HTML.  Thanks!

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do... are you just looking for `console.log(people);`?

Comment: does `response.list` return an array? If so, try writing an iterative function that cycles through your `people` array, and for each item, `console.log(people[i]);`.

Answer (score 0):

if **response.list** is an array/collection then you can use the following code to ierate it

```
$.each(response.list function(index, value) { 
  console.log(index + ': ' + value); 
});
```

The `$.each()` function can be used to iterate over any collection, whether it is a map (JavaScript object) or an array. In the case of an array, the callback is passed an array index and a corresponding array value each time. for more info on `$.each()` try this [post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)